# Nissan Qashqai camera recorder

Tags: nissan, camera

I've placed an order for a new Nissan Qashqai and we've gone with the Tekna grade that comes with front, back and side cameras. I've seen that people have started to kit their cars out with cameras to catch accidents, so I wonder if I can put the two together.

Has any tried it? I'm sure it's *possible* but wonder whether it'll void the warranty or not.

Answer (score 2):

It would require a degree of hacking the system, so I'm not sure if it's worthwhile if you want to preserve the warranty.

I'd expect that there are two options for doing this:

1. Custom firmware or software for the system, which enables recording (unlikely), or
2. Using splitters on the camera video outputs and having a separate device which records them (requires splicing cables)

Answer (score 0):

There's a law for this in the US, the Magnuson-Moss Act. Warranties cannot be voided do to aftermarket parts that really have no effect on other systems, see:

http://www.impalaclub.com/naisso/magmoss.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnuson%E2%80%93Moss_Warranty_Act

Comment: So are there kits you can buy? Potentially ones that work with Nissans?

Comment: @AhmedNuaman, I think I misunderstood your question. This video system is an option specific to the Nissan, it sounds like, so you would be hacking your existing system up to record. This may be as easy as diverting the video cables to a added DVR, or if the format from the cameras is proprietary, a lot more work...